# SQL: Why am i suddenly getting 2 million more rows from this statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The original statement is:

```
Select
     A.a,
     B.b
FROM
     A,
     B
WHERE
     A.c = B.C
```

I add this and get 2 million more rows :

```
Select
     A.a,
     B.b,
     C.d
FROM
     A,
     B,
     C
WHERE
     A.c = B.C
     AND
     C.c = A.c
```

The table C I am trying to add is only 55,000 rows Where as the other two tables are much larger.

Comment: Yet another reason to drop the old-style join syntax and finally start using the ANSI JOIN's - INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you've accidentally generated a bit of a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). It seems likely that some table has multiple rows with the same C value, and you're getting duplicates. Take a look at the uniqueness of C in each of those tables.

I'd rewrite it using the clearer and more explicit new style join syntax:

```
SELECT A.a, B.b, C.d
FROM A
JOIN B on A.c = B.c
JOIN C on A.c = C.c
```

Answer (score 6):

You're getting the cross product rather than doing a real join.  This is exceedingly expensive.

I'd recommend rewriting it to be:

```
select a.a, b.b, c.d
from a
join b on a.c = b.c
join c on c.c = a.c
```

It will be significantly faster and likely give you the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

when you use the join syntax

```
FROM A, B, C
```

your result set will be the product of

rows from A * # of rows from B * # of rows from C

so if each table has 1000 rows your result set will have 1,000,000,000 rows

Comment: You ignored the WHERE clause specified.  The Cartesian product only is guaranteed to occur if there are no constraints on the joins

Comment: true...but the reason for the more rows is because of the cartesian product, i was just trying to share WHY it was happening...

Answer (score -1):

hm... I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you prolly want to do something like this so C.c will match B.C too... look the below code:

```
Select
     A.a,
     B.b,
     C.d
FROM
     A,
     B,
     C
WHERE
     A.c = B.C
     AND
     C.c = A.c
     AND
     C.c = B.C
```

Your code are trying to join B, C with A individually.